# How can I ensure Coverity recognizes a higher version number?

Tags: coverity

I submitted to Coverity Version number v1.2-94-gc6a092c previously and now followed up with version v1.2-131-g122f226. These numbers are generated by `git describe`

The project dashboard still shows version v1.2-94-gc6a092c.

What is necessary for Coverity to see a version number as higher than the previous one?